# CHECK constraint matching beginning of value

Tags: sqlite, constraints, sql-like, create-table, check-constraints

We are using sqlite3 for a database and ensuring values inserted into a column matching a specific string would be useful in our case.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE people ("firstname" TEXT),
CHECK(LIKE('ca%',"firstname"));
```

The error we see is that sqlite3 gives this error:

```
Parse error: near "CHECK": syntax error
  CREATE TABLE people ("firstname" TEXT), CHECK(LIKE('ca%',"firstname"));
                            error here ---^
```

We want this be ok:

```
INSERT INTO people VALUES ('Callie');
```

but this be not ok:

```
INSERT INTO people VALUES ('Erik');
```

Is a CHECK with this possible in sqlite3? there is LIKE but everybody seem to only mention SELECT statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct syntax for the constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
  firstname TEXT,
  CHECK (firstname LIKE 'ca%')
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/XYlAiucW).

Comment: This worked flawlessly, many thanks